# How would you create and then delete a file called "$SHELL"? Try it

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How would you create and then delete a file called `$SHELL`?

Comment: You asking about $SHELL? $SHELL is binary file which is mapped under your linux environment. You can not create or delete any file with name $SHELL

Comment: if you want to create file with $SHEEL then you can use it with single quoted word like '$SHEEL'

Answer (score 3):

if you want to create file with $SHEEL then you can use it with single quoted word like '$SHEEL'.

For creation use

```
touch '$SHEEL'
```

For deletion use

```
rm '$SHEEL'
```